# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.getSource

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I was trying to run a aws glue job locally in my system . The code is working in aws glue.

But while running locally, i am having the below issue for "Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.getSource " . Can anyone help me to understand how to  debug this error . I have placed (2.17.1,2.19.1 , 2.20.0 and 2.21.1 log4j-api and core jars in the classpath  ) . i have only on version of python installed in my system 3.11

here is the stack trace :

```
Platform is local :: GLUE_ENV = False
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/opt/spark-3.4.1-bin-hadoop3/jars/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/opt/spark-3.4.1-bin-hadoop3/jars/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
23/11/15 10:18:11 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
C:\opt\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\context.py:112: FutureWarning: Deprecated in 3.0.0. Use SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() instead.
  warnings.warn(
23/11/15 10:18:13 INFO GlueContext: GlueMetrics not configured
23/11/15 10:18:13 INFO GlueContext: fs.s3.impl hadoop configuration is not set. Setting fs.s3.impl to org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem

23/11/15 10:18:14 INFO AvroReaderUtil$: Creating default Avro field parser for version 1.7.
23/11/15 10:18:14 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 192.9 KiB, free 434.2 MiB)
23/11/15 10:18:14 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 32.4 KiB, free 434.2 MiB)
23/11/15 10:18:14 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on XXXLD-2412WKB.usXXX001:53175 (size: 32.4 KiB, free: 434.4 MiB)
23/11/15 10:18:14 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DynamoConnection.scala:52
23/11/15 10:18:14 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 192.9 KiB, free 434.0 MiB)
23/11/15 10:18:14 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 32.4 KiB, free 434.0 MiB)
23/11/15 10:18:14 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on LD-2412WKB.us. (size: 32.4 KiB, free: 434.3 MiB)
23/11/15 10:18:14 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DynamoConnection.scala:52
23/11/15 10:18:14 INFO JobBookmark$: jobbookmark is not enabled, do not init AWSGlueJobBookMarkService
23/11/15 10:18:14 INFO GlueLogger: 
23/11/15 10:18:14 INFO GlueContext: Glue secret manager integration: secretId is not provided.
23/11/15 10:18:14 INFO AWSConnectionUtils$: AWSConnectionUtils: use proxy in glue client configuration. Host: null, Port: -1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\opt\datalake\templates\inbound-db\inbound_db\inbound_db.py", line 62, in <module>
    glue_df = get_inbound_glue_df(glue_spark, inbound_db_config["input"])
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\opt\datalake\templates\inbound-db\inbound_db\handlers\inbound_df.py", line 56, in get_inbound_glue_df
    glue_df = glue_spark.glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\opt\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\awsglue\dynamicframe.py", line 609, in from_options
    return self._glue_context.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\opt\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\awsglue\context.py", line 232, in create_dynamic_frame_from_options
    source = self.getSource(connection_type, format, transformation_ctx, push_down_predicate, **connection_options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\opt\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\awsglue\context.py", line 104, in getSource
    j_source = self._ssql_ctx.getSource(connection_type,
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\opt\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\opt\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py", line 169, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\opt\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.getSource.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.ClassLoader org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocatorUtil.getCallerClassLoader(int)'
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:40)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.DataCatalogWrapperUtils.$init$(DataCatalogWrapper.scala:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.DataCatalogWrapper.<init>(DataCatalogWrapper.scala:165)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.dataCatalogWrapperValue$lzycompute(GlueContext.scala:206)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.dataCatalogWrapperValue(GlueContext.scala:205)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.dataCatalogWrapper(GlueContext.scala:208)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.applyConnectionProperties(GlueContext.scala:1074)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getSourceInternal(GlueContext.scala:979)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getSource(GlueContext.scala:840)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)

23/11/15 10:18:15 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook

Process finished with exit code 1
```

```
things i did to resolve this as below
```

1. Copied the jar from apache log4j site and placed in the class path of aws glue and spark home folder .
2. i have uninstalled a previous version of python ,hence i have one version of python in my system